# use htaccess to remove www from root and subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having an issue with my htaccess. I am trying to remove www. from my root and subdirectories. However, every example I have tried redirects to root.

IE www.example.com -> example.com But www.example.com/blog -> example.com

I need to remove www. from all directories and subdirectories, and keep the original path intended.

IE www.example.com -> example.com AND www.example.com/blog -> example.com/blog

I have used the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

(Edit- after asked if I hade code above it)

I used this and it worked correctly

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I did not know drupal changed the way .htaccess worked. I apologize for not including that I was using this CMS in my original question

Comment: Should work like you did. Have you some other rules before it ?

Comment: @JustinIurman Actually yes..

Comment: I used this and it worked correctly

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

I did not know drupal changed the way .htaccess worked. I apologize for not including that I was using this CMS in my question. Hopefully this will help someone in the future. Could someone link the the code as the answer so I can check the box.

Comment: @user3263759 you can create your own answer and accept it in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```